# Checkbox doesn't render

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is what I did on the view. I put `@Html.CheckBox("checkBox", false, "Name")` in a jQuery UI tab.

But on the rendered html, this checkbox control was evaluated as a html string

```
<input id="checkBox" name="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="checkBox" type="hidden" value="false" /><label for="checkBox">Name</label>
```

rather than a control. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The default for Html.CheckBox also creates a hidden input tag.

This will return the value you get when the checkbox is not checked. Due to the nature of html, if a checkbox is not checked, nothing will be posted. So this is the easiest workaround.